# spring jdbcdaosupport returns null

Tags: spring, jdbc, dao, jdbctemplate

I have searched in every corner of the web with no result. 
I'm using Spring and trying to inject Jdbc operations into my DaoImpl class.

Seems like I am missing something as the DaoImpl class is returning null when querying for something, what am I doing wrong?

Bean configurations:

```
 <bean id="transactionDao" class="jdbc.dao.OracleTransactionDao">
            <property name="jdbcTemplate" ref="jdbcTemplate" />
        </bean>

        <bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
            <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        </bean>


        <!-- ORACLE CONNECTION -->
        <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
            destroy-method="close">
            <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
            <property name="url" value="${url}" />
            <property name="username" value="${dbname}" />
            <property name="password" value="${dbpassword}" />
        </bean>
```

Interface dao:

```
interface TransactionDao extends Serializable {
    public abstract void insert (Transaction transaction);
```

As you can see in the bean config, and in this class below, I'm currently both trying to inject the JdbcTemplate and trying to use the extended methods of JdbcDaoSupport 
Implementation dao:

```
OracleTransactionDao extends JdbcDaoSupport implements
TransactionDao {
    @Autowired
    JdbcTemplate              template;

    @Override
    public void insert (Transaction transaction) {
        List<Map<String, Object>> list;
        try{
            list = template
                    .queryForList("SELECT * FROM CUSTOMER");
        }catch(NullPointerException e) {
            list = this.queryForList("SELECT * FROM CUSTOMER");
        }
        System.out.println("called insert" + list.size());

    }
```

My main:
    ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
                      "beanConfigs.xml");
            context.registerShutdownHook();
            OracleTransactionDao dao = (OracleTransactionDao) context
                      .getBean("transactionDao");

I must be missing some detail here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please set driverName to "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver" and see if it works

Comment: The driver is working in main, so I don't think its the driver.. Its something with the injection of the jdbctemplate into my DaoObj, I' ve found a workaround for now, injecting the context to the DaoObj and then instasiating a static jdbctemplate inside my DaoObjImpl and the driver is not complaining.. Thanks

Comment: Thats weird, because I have created unit test for your scenario and it works

Comment: And the only diff is the driver you mesn?

Answer (score 0):

Unit test i mentioned in a comment.
spring-context.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc.xsd">


  <bean id="transactionDao" class="jdbc.dao.TransactionDao">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
  </bean>

  <bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
  </bean>

  <jdbc:embedded-database id="dataSource" type="H2" />

</beans>
```

TransactionDao:

```
public class TransactionDao extends JdbcDaoSupport {
    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate template;

    public List<Map<String, Object>> insert() {
        String sql = "CREATE TABLE REGISTRATION " +
                "(id INTEGER not NULL, " +
                " first VARCHAR(255), " +
                " last VARCHAR(255), " +
                " age INTEGER, " +
                " PRIMARY KEY ( id ))";

        template.execute(sql);
        return template.queryForList("select * from registration");
    }
}
```

TransactionDaoTest:

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath*:spring-context.xml"})
public class TransactionDaoTest extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests {

    @Autowired
    private TransactionDao transactionDao;

    @Test
    public void testJdbcTemplateNotNull(){
        Assertions.assertThat(transactionDao.insert()).isNotNull();
    }
}
```

pom.xml (some deps are not needed):

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-framework-bom</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>

  <dependencies>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
      <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
      <version>3.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
      <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
      <version>18.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
      <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
      <version>6.9.4</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
      <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.0</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
      <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
      <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
      <version>1.4.187</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>



  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

Comment: Yes but you have to take into account that this is still in the same context, your test,
I too have it working when calling it from main, but add some JMS EJB listeners and asynch' messages coming in, 
what happens I think is the threading, since the Main thread exits before the messageListener calls on the DaoObj, when in DaoObj the JdbcTemplate is null, as I mentioned, when injecting the context to the DaoObj and making it ApplicationContextAware, I also have it working, but I would like to believe there is a better way to do it?

Comment: My guess would be that this class is not instantiated by Spring. The easiest way to check that is to put a breakpoint in your TransactionDao and see the stacktrace - make sure its run by Spring

Comment: And what would be the cause of that?

Answer (score 0):

Basically came around this issue by injecting the context to the OracleTransactionDao

```
OracleTransactionDao implements TransactionDao,
          ApplicationContextAware {
    private static JdbcOperations jdbc;

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext (ApplicationContext context) {
        this.jdbc = context.getBean(JdbcOperations.class);
    }
```

all I had to add in the beanConfig

```
<bean id="transactionDao" class="jdbc.dao.OracleTransactionDao">
</bean>
```

If anyone has a better looking solution please advise